# How to update ENV variables in a Process without restarting it (NodeJS)?

Tags: node.js, shell, terminal, process, restart

I have a server running on NodeJS. Is there a way to update the environment variables in the process without restarting the server?

What I'm looking to do is:

1. Start my server `npm start`
2. `type something into the console to update ENV variable`
3. Server restarts with new environment variable

Comment: What process manager/OS are you using?

Comment: I'm using Mac OS

Answer (score 5):

From a programmatic standpoint, you should be able to update the `process.env` variable that was passed into the running process.

For example, running:

```
cmd_line$: MY_VALUE=some_val node ./index.js
```

with code:

```
console.log(process.env.MY_VALUE)
process.env.MY_VALUE = 'some other value'
console.log(process.env.MY_VALUE)
process.env.MY_VALUE = 4
console.log(process.env.MY_VALUE)
```

output in terminal:

```
some_val
some other value
4
```

From a server admin standpoint for an already running application, I don't know the answer to that.

Answer (score 5):

It's possible to debug Node.js process and change global variables:

[image: debug]

On *nix, it's possible to enable debugging even if a process wasn't started in debug mode. On Windows, it's possible to debug only processes that were started with `node --inspect`. [This article](https://hackernoon.com/debugging-node-without-restarting-processes-bd5d5c98f200) explains both possibilities in detail.

Obviously, this will work only if environment variables are used directly all the time as `process.env.FOO`.

If their values are initially used, changing `process.env.FOO` later may not affect anything:

```
const FOO = process.env.FOO;
...
console.log(FOO); // it doesn't matter whether process.env.FOO was changed at this point
```

Answer (score 3):

If you make a change to env variables they will take place immediately only if you make the change via the main Properties dialog for the system which is going to my computer -> Advanced properties -> Environment Variables.

Any program which is already running will not see the changes unless we handle it in the code explicitly.

Logic behind it is that there is an agent which sends a broadcasting a WM_SETTINGCHANGE message and make changes to all applications inorder to notify for that change.

Comment: This is kind of what I want, but I am looking to see if there is a way to do this on the console directly

Answer (score 1):

`process.env.WHATEVER = ...` updates an object, and if you `console.log(process.env.WHATEVER)`, you're gonna log that value, and it does not have to do with the actual env. Other parts of your *current* program can now access `process.env.WHATEVER` because it is a path on a global variable *inside* the JavaScript program.

But! If you want to execute child programs and expect them to have the same `env` as your current process, you need to *explicitly* pass your env around to the exec/spawn commands. F.e.:

```
exec('echo $WHATEVER', {env: process.env})
```

Similar with spawn, etc.

If you do not pass an `env` to the child-process-creating commands, they will not inherit the env from the parent process automatically.

You can also set the `env` to something entirely different than the parent.

Answer (score 0):

[Here's a good explanation](https://medium.com/@himanshuagarwal1395/setting-up-environment-variables-in-macos-sierra-f5978369b255) on how to setup environment variables in mac OS. Additionally, as others have already answered, you can set them with `process.env.ANY_VARIABLE = 'some value'`.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to find a cross-platform answer to this (mac, linux, windows)

For mac, a workaround that I found is using

```
const shell = require("shelljs");  

console.log(shell.exec('launchctl getenv TEST'));
```

It only works if you set environment variable (e.g. in other terminal tab) using `launchctl setenv TEST blahblah`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use this javascript tiny library to update env variables without restarting the node server:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/runtime-node-refresh

Hope this help.