# Environment variable is not updated in windows machine

Tags: javascript, node.js, environment-variables

I am working on a nodejs app, I want to perform some action when environment variable is set to '1' and different action when environment variable is set to '0'.

I manually change the value of this variable from '0' to '1'. I still value '0' being printed. It didn't recognize the value change. Is there any better to read value from registry?

**Note: I use process.env.variable_name**

Here is the code snippet

```
function setVar () {
    if(process.env.Env_Variable_test) { 
        console.log('It is set!'); 
        console.log(process.env.Env_Variable_test);
    }
    else { 
        console.log('No set!'); 
        console.log(process.env.Env_Variable_test);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: As per my knowledge, when the nodejs process starts process.env will be loaded and if you want to change the env variable you will have to restart the process.

Comment: Thanks I see that , I have to exit the process then restart the process once again

Comment: Are there any better way to read the registry value

Comment: Not sure, check out this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51446149/how-to-update-env-variables-in-a-process-without-restarting-it-nodejs/51446308